# Reserved word for rails application name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new rails 3.2.3 application giving it a name - jquery.

```
rails new jquery
```

Right after I created it, "rails console" gives me the following error.

```
~/Temp/jquery$ r c
/Users/ssk/Temp/jquery/config/application.rb:13: uninitialized constant Jquery::Rails::Application (NameError)
    from /Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:39
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

If I create it with different name, it's ok.
So jquery is not allowed name?
If so, how do I know if a name is allowed or now before I create one?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of Reserved Words for Rails you can check out.

http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords